# running on an SD card issue

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard

I recently modified all my apps to run on an SD card by specifying 
android:installLocation="preferExternal" in the Manifest.xml.  They tested out just fine on all my test phones.

It seems like a no-brainer for an app to allow this.  But I notice that most of the apps on my phones do not allow running on an SD card.  Google Chrome, Google Earth, Dropbox, Google Gmail, GolfNow, etc.  In fact none of the Google apps will run on an SD Card.

I'm trying to find out why.  What is the downside of running on an SD card?
Thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a broad question and you'd really have to ask the developers of those apps to get a definitive answer.

Some ideas...

- External storage as it's traditionally known was usually provided by plug in SD cards. An SD card can, of course, be dismounted and/or physically removed by the user meaning none of the apps installed on it will work until it is reinserted.
- Certain types of RAM chips have much faster access times than others. Internal RAM on a device might be better suited for processor / computational intensive apps than that of accessing SD cards which tend to have slower access times both at the RAM chip level and also due to having to go through an external bus.
- Mission critical apps (depending on the users' defination of what they should be) need to be accessible permanently (see my first point). If a user wants their email to be retrieved at short, fixed intervals, their email app can't be allowed to disappear because the external storage has been dismounted / removed.
- There are known problems with some app requirements which cause unpredictable results when the app is installed on an SD card. A classic example is any app which registers a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive the `BOOT_COMPLETED` action. Boot completion happens *BEFORE* various parts of a device are up and running - this includes mounting the SD card. In this scenario, the broadcast is sent but the apps on the SD card aren't running and can't receive it.
- As time has gone on, so called 'internal' and 'external' storage definitions have become increasingly blurred - in comparison to several years ago, many Android devices have huge amounts of 'internal' memory making it less important to free up space by installing or moving apps to 'external' storage. Some devices don't even have the ability to add an external SD card and 'external' storage is emulated from a partition on the 'internal' storage.
- One other point (tongue in cheek) - perhaps the developers of the apps you mention are egomaniacs and just insist on using up precious 'internal' storage just because they can. ;)

Comment: Actually, relatively few devices implement their "External Storage" as a removable SD card.  There are exceptions, but for a few years now, most emulate it using the *same* bucket of flash blocks used for the internal.  But just about none use "RAM chips" for their storage.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : As I mentioned in one of my points - more recent devices emulate so-called external storage for legacy reasons. There are still "old" devices around which, I for one still support. My ageing HTC Desire (original model) which I use on a daily basis has been around for 5 years, still runs Froyo and only has an SD card as an option for external storage. Apologies for my use of the archaic term "RAM chips" - I've been playing with electronics since I was a kid (and qualified as an Electronics engineer in 1985) I still generalise terms based on what their function is.

Comment: "RAM" does not historically apply to the role filled by flash today or discussed in the question - the question concerns the role that was filled by disk or tape in an earlier era.

Comment: Squonk, Thanks.  Good recap.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the downside of running on an SD card

Depends on the app. If i.e. your app listens to broadcasts, uses Alarm Manager etc. then it must not be on SD card for this to work. If your app is not using any of these, then it simply makes no difference from developer standpoint.

Comment: All of my apps use Google Cloud Messaging and I receive those messages via a broadcast receiver and it works perfectly on an SD Card.